# About definition of perfect set in subspace topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have question about the definition of perfect set in subspace topology. $A\subset \Bbb R$ is perfect set  if it is closed and has no isolated point. Let $X$ be a topological space and $Y$ be a subspace of $X$. Let $A\subset Y$ be a perfect set. Under which conditions we can say that $A$ is a perfect set of $X$.

Comment: If it has no isolated point as a subset of $Y$, then it certainly has no isolated point as a subset of $X$, so it will be perfect as a subset of $X$ if and only if it is closed in $X$. This will automatically be true if $Y$ is closed in $X$, but it can be true even when $Y$ is not closed in $X$. For instance, the irrationals are not closed in $\Bbb R$, but there are subsets of the irrationals that are Cantor sets and therefore are perfect in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, Thank you are very helpfully as usual. One more thing, If $P$ is  a perfect set in $X$, then $P'=P\cap Y$ is perfect in $Y$ .Right?

Comment: Not necessarily: in general $P\cap Y$ could even be finite.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, You are right. Thank you

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, for integer $k$, choose a perfect set $P_k\subset(k,k+1)$ . Then $\bigcup _{k<\omega} P_k$ is perfect, but in which space .

Comment: Perfect in $\Bbb R$: it’s clearly closed in $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Z$, and it’s easy to see that no integer is in its closure.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, but I choose  them in $(k,k+1)$ this is why I got confused.They are perfect in $(k,k+1)$

Comment: Sorry, I wasn’t thinking clearly. The union will be perfect in $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Z$, and it will be perfect in $\Bbb R$ if and only it’s closed in $\Bbb R$, which will be the case if and only if the sets $P_k$ are compact.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, sorry but it is still not clear . Consider this case $P_k\subset(a, b)$ is perfect pairwise disjoint sets. So, $\bigcup_{k<\omega} P_k$ is perfect set in $[a,b]$. Does that work? Thank you.

Comment: In that case $\bigcup_kP_k$ is perfect in $[a,b]$ iff there are $c,d\in(a,b)$ such that $\bigcup_kP_k\subseteq[c,d]$, which is true iff $\bigcup_kP_k$ is compact. Otherwise at least one of $a$ and $b$ will be limit points of $\bigcup_kP_k$ in $[a,b]$, and $\bigcup_kP_k$ won’t be closed in $[a,b]$.